# How do I use CONCATENATE, COUNTIFS and OR?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to count cases of blanks or n/a using the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIFS(range,"n/a",range,""),"/16")
```

Using this formula, it is using **and** rather than **or**.

What do I need to add to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you paste a small example table, and the result of what you get when running your code, and what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sum the two using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(range,{"n/a",""})) & "/16"
```